# Is authentication using Firebase free or limited by number of connections?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

I am having trouble regarding what is the status of Authentication using Firebase (email/password and google sign-in).

**Is it free or limited by the number of connections?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) the authentication is free and not limited by the number of connections. Except for phone authentication, which is limited to 10k/Month on free tier.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase authentication is **free** and not limited by the number of users.
But phone authentication(with OTP) is limited to 10k users per month on free tier.
For firebase pricing [click here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)